# How to show origin axis with spb.plot_implicit()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

I am trying to get plot_implicit from spb to show the origin x and y axis. I can toggle the grid lines by adding grid=False in the parameters, I can't figure out how to toggle the origin axis. I have tried accessing the the backend through plot.backend and plot._backend, but I get the error "MatplotlibObject" has no attribute backend, etc.

```
from sympy import *
import spb
x, y = symbols("x, y")
expr = real_root(x**2, 3) + real_root(y**2, 3) - real_root(16, 3)
plot = spb.plot_implicit(expr,grid=False)
ax = plot.ax
ax.set_xlim(-5,5)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `axis_center="center"` on the function call, like this.

```py
plot = spb.plot_implicit(expr,grid=False, axis_center="center")
```

For more customization options, read `help(spb.MB)`.

Comment: A hero as always Davide!